# Why can I not access postgres when running it as a service?

Tags: macos, postgresql, psql

When I try to access postgres via a webapp, or open the postgres shell with `psql -d template1`, I get an error.

> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory  Is the
>   server running locally and accepting  connections on Unix domain
>   socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

(*I've read a number of SO threads about this error, but recommended solutions did not fix this for me)

**Start postgres as a service:**

```
brew services restart postgresql
```

> Stopping `postgresql`... (might take a while)
>       ==> Successfully stopped `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)
>       ==> Successfully started `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)

**Manually run postgres in a terminal:**

I can get everything to work by running below in a terminal window, but I would prefer to run it in the background.

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres9.6.3
```

**Clusters:**

I have 3 db clusters in `/usr/local/var`, but I would like to use `postgres9.6.3/`

```
postgres
postgres9.5/
postgres9.6.3/
```

**Which:**

`which psql` returns `/usr/local/bin/psql`

**Path:**

`echo $PATH` returns `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/var` (added)

**Other recommended solutions:**

A lot of people where able to fix this by removing a `/postgres/postmaster.pid`, but this file doesn't exist for me.

## UPDATE

Running `ps -ef | grep postgres`, outputs only,

```
501  2135  1530   0 12:08pm ttys002    0:00.00 grep postgres
```

After restarting postgres with `brew servies`, `postgres.log` in `/usr/local/var/log` contains,

```
FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.5, which is not compatible with this version 9.6.3.
```

Comment: After you restart the service through `brew services`, does the output of `ps -ef | grep postgres` show anything? If not, the server isn't actually running -- which seems likely, given the error. Check the logs (should be in /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log) and see if there's anything interesting in there.

Comment: Added an update to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use your 9.5 data with 9.6 server. you have to run:

- `pg_upgrade`([here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgupgrade.html)) or
- `pg_dump` from 9.5 to file and `pg_restore` | `psql` depending on backup type on 9.6... ([here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup.html))

if you choose first option, no further steps needed - your default version is 9.6 and it will work with existing data directory.

**before running `pg_upgrade`, make a cold copy of data_directory**

Answer (score 3):

The service definition is still specifying your old 9.5 data directory. If you open ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist you should see a section that looks like this:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
  <string>/usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres</string>
  <string>-D</string>
  <string>/usr/local/var/postgres9.5</string>
</array>
```

Change the final argument to point to your 9.6.3 data directory and restart the service. If it doesn't take you may need to log out and back in so it re-reads the plist.

Comment: I was able to open and edit this file (it showed the old version). But it reverts  to the old version after I update it if i restart postgres with `brew services restart postgres`. Is there another way I need to update it than `sudo nano...`

Comment: The default data directory for Homebrew installations is [/usr/local/var/postgres](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Installers/Mac_OS_X). If you switch the directories around you should be able to upgrade without worrying about it.